# getting img node from parent

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following html and I want to get the image "src" value. The php I am using does not return anything. I don't get any errors and I'm not sure if the code is wrong or what is going on?

```
<a class="main-img" href="/product/index.jsp">
  <img src="14402813t241x292.jpg" height="292" width="241">
</a>
```

I've tried the following with no success.

```
$img = $xpath->query("//img");
$img = $xpath->query("//a[@class='main-img']/img");
$img = $xpath->query("//img/@src");
$img = $xpath->query("//a[@class='main-img']/img/@src");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last XPath is good.

```
//a[@class="main-img"]/img/@src
```

[It works](http://ideone.com/qFD5Yl).

Note query returns a node set. So you need to Iterated over it to get all nodes.

Comment: When I run, it throws `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: curl_data in /home/shiplu/src/xpath-image.php on line 33`. But outputs a lot of image paths. See this http://ideone.com/sycAzt